# Location of login/autostart apps setting file in macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, login, settings, login-items

Under System Preferences → Users & Groups → **Current User** → Login items, a list of applications is maintained that will open automatically upon login:

[image]

I would like to share these settings across two different Macs. Where are these stored exactly in macOS filesystem?

Answer (score 5):

Part of the list is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist` under the LoginHook key.

Also you'll find a set of LaunchAgents stored in this folder:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Each of the files in there detail a program that is started when your user account logs in.

There's also a similar list in `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` that are run when any user logs in, so they're not specific to your user.

In earlier versions of macOS it was also usual to place startup items in `/Library/StartupItems` and `/System/Library/StartupItems`. But they're usually not in use anymore.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I've posted, there's "IntelliJ IDEA" application, which I've added manually, for the current user only. I can't see that in any of the places you're describing.